# Change color using string replace method

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to change color using string replace method.

If I run the following, I obtain the right output:

1)

```
>>> print('this \033[31m-text-\033[0m is red' )
```

2)
If I try to run the following I don’t get the expected output but just:

```
>>> "this --- is red".replace('---', '\033[31m-text-\033[0m')
'this \x1b[31m-text-\x1b[0m is red'
```

3)
If I try the following I get an error:

```
>>> eval ("this --- is red".replace('---', '\033[31m-text-\033[0m'))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 1
    this -text- is red
         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

How should run the code to obtain the result as in 1) by using  string replace method.

Comment: Why don't you just use `print` instead of `eval`?

Comment: print will give the same output

Comment: @PadraicCunningham: As what? It won't give the same output as either dumping the `repr` or calling `eval`.

Comment: @abarnert Maybe he meant "the same as (1)"

Comment: @abarnert, yes that is exactly what I meant, how will it not give the same result?

Answer (score 1):

#### TL;DR

Just use `print "this --- is red".replace('---', '\033[31m-text-\033[0m')`.

#### Why your versions don't work

Version 2) just outputs the string with the interpreter. This means that `repr` is called on it before outputting, so that the escape character is escaped as `\x1b`. This is also why the single quotes around the output are shown.

Version 3) tries to evaluate the string as code. Because `this -text- is red` is not valid Python, it raises a `SyntaxError`. If you use `print` instead of `eval` to output your string, the output will be correct.